# Check for integer value vs float value

Tags: vba, floating-point, integer

I
My vba doesnt seem to quite work. I need it to multiply a value in column N by 2 if it is a decimal and do nothing for all other values.

currently it is

```
Sub multiply()
Dim i, j, k, l As Integer

Dim n As Variant

i = Application.InputBox("enter end row")

j = Application.InputBox("enter factor")

For k = 1 To i

n = Cells(k, 14) * j

If VarType(n) = vbSingle Then Cells(k, 14) = n

Next k

End Sub
```

This does nothing. Dont know why

Answer (score 1):

Your `For` loop can be written like this:

```
For k = 1 To i

    If Cells(k, 14) <> Int(Cells(k, 14)) Then 'if it's decimal
        Cells(k, 14) = Cells(k, 14) * j 'then multiply cell by factor
    End If

Next k
```

Note that I determine whether it's decimal by checking if the `Int()` of that number is different than the number itself.

A couple of tips:

- If it's always the end row you look for, you don't need to ask the input to the user. You can use `endRow = Cells(1,14).End(xlDown).Row` (assuming your data starts from the first cell of the column 14).
- Use better naming of the variables, you will thank yourself if you'll re-read this code in few weeks. For example, `j` should be called `multiplyFactor`, `i` should be called `endRow`.
- When you write `Dim i, j, k, l As Integer`, you are declaring `i`, `j` and `k` as `Variant` (default type) and only `l` as `Integer` that you're not even using in your code (at least not in what you posted). You should write instead `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer`.